# Regex for string split twice

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string which is split twice in array. Here is an example:

```
Obj1:Val1|Obj2:Val2|Obj3:Val3
```

Please help me with the regular expression to fetch the array of first string:

```
Obj1
Obj2
Obj3
```

And then another regex to fetch

```
Val1
Val2
Val3
```

I do not want to iterate. I want the result from regex in one go.

Comment: Whats the language you are using? and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am using c# but would it matter?

Comment: Yes its very important.

Comment: It is important because regex engines are not the same, there are differences in parsing algorithms  and the pattern definition language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using C# you can first split your string with `|` then you will have list of strings with `:` as those delimiter so you can then split the sub lists with `:` and use [`zip` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427015/how-to-do-pythons-zip-in-c) to get the list of objects and values.

But as a straight way you can use following regexes :

[for values](https://regex101.com/r/wO8aM2/1) (the first group):

```
:(.*?)(\||$)
```

[for objects](https://regex101.com/r/wO8aM2/2) (the second group):

```
(\||^)(.*?):
```

Comment: This gives : and | characters as well in the result. How to trim those?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to split:

```
[:|]
```

And even indexes will give `Obj1 Obj2 Obj3` and fetch `Val1 Val2 Val3` from odd indexes of the array

Or..

You can split the regex with `[|]` and then split each value with `[:]`.. storing [0] in one array and [1] in another array..

**Edit:**

For list of `Obj`'s you can split with following regex:

```
:\w+(?:\||$)
```

For list of `Val`'s you can split with foloowing regex:

```
(?:^|\|)\w+:
```

Comment: This would not fetch the list of all Obj*

Comment: I do not want to iterate. I want the result from Regex in one go

Comment: This gives : and | characters as well in the result. How to trim those?

Answer (score 1):

Use named match captures to extract the information. The below regex gets the key value (the first one) and the value value (the second one) and ultimately creates Key Value pair object.

```
string data ="Obj1:Val1|Obj2:Val2|Obj3:Val3";
string pattern = @"(?<Key>[^:]+):(?<Value>[^|]+)+\|?";

  Regex.Matches(data, pattern)
       .OfType<Match>()
       .Select (mt => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(mt.Groups["Key"].Value,  
                                                      mt.Groups["Value"].Value) );
```

*Note the `KeyValuePair` projection is optional, you can simply extract the information via `mt.Groups["Key"].Value` on its own.*

Here is the result of the above regex/linq projection:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a regex. Use Split and LINQ:

```
var str = "Obj1:Val1|Obj2:Val2|Obj3:Val3";
var arr = str.Split(new[] {'|',':'});
// And then either these 2 lines to get Objs and Vals into different arrays
var vals  = arr.Where((c,i) => i % 2 != 0).ToArray();
var objs = arr.Where((c,i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray();
// Or into a key-value pair array
var key_value_array = 
     arr.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0)
        .Zip(arr.Where((c, i) => i % 2 != 0), 
             (key, value) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value))
        .ToArray();
```

Output:

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Calling `ToList()` on `arr` is unnecessary because the underlying object is not *queryable*; for split returns a enumerable string[] result.

Comment: Yes, You are right. No need converting `string[]` to `List<string>`, updated. I just was not sure, and had no way to check.

Comment: Use Linqpad. Also add this to your answer to `Zip` up the results into a KeyValue pair:  `arr.Where((c,i) => i % 2 != 0)
   .Zip(arr.ToList().Where((c,i) => i % 2 == 0) , 
        (key, value) => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(key,value))`

Comment: Oops reverse my logic on the where, for key and value.

Comment: @OmegaMan: Thank you for the hint. Now, it seems there is plenty of choice for OP :)

Comment: I require a regex and not a LINQ. It again iterates through

Comment: Please describe a solution you are seeking. It is not clear now how you want it to be done. Please show us the code you are using, it may help us understand your approach.

Answer (score 0):

To get `Obj` matches you can **split** by:

```
:[^|]+(?:\||$)
```

And to get `Val` strings **split** by:

```
(^|\|)[^:]+:
```