# How to iterate two non-trivial class object's properties at the same time in C# similar to Python's zip method

Tags: c#, python, .net, reflection, iterator

How do I iterate two non-trivial class objects at the same time to check their properties?

These [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427015/how-to-do-pythons-zip-in-c) [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297124/how-to-combine-more-than-two-generic-lists-in-c-sharp-zip) talks about how to do it with generic default data structures, but what if it is a custom class and I cannot modify it, say, something like

```
public class A
{
   public int propA { get; set; }
   public int propB { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Also it does not have a `GetEnumerator()` method. How do I do something similar to Python's zip while using reflection? So I can do something like:

```
foreach(var pair in zip(myClassObj1.GetType().GetProperties(), myClasObj2.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   var name1 = pair.Item1.Name;
   var name2 = pair.Item2.Name;

   var value1 = pair.Item1.GetValue(myClassObj1, null);
   var value2 = pair.Item2.GetValue(myClassObj2, null);

   // do things
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110781/10297190) gave me the tools needed to for enumerating the properties of the two classes in one foreach loop

```
foreach(var prop in obj1.GetType().GetProperites().Zip(obj2.GetType().GetProperties(), (a,b) => Tuple.Create(a,b))
{
    var name1 = prop.Item1.Name;
    var name2 = prop.Item2.Name;

    var value1 = prop.Item1.GetValue(obj1, null);
    var value2 = prop.Item2.GetValue(obj2, null);

    // do things
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reflection for that (`System.Reflection`). First of all, you need to get the **Type** object of the object of the object you want to get all the properties from. Then, call the method *GetProperties()*, which will return an array of **PropertyInfo** objects. Then run all over that objects collecting the info you need.

```
public static IDictionary<string, object> GetAllProperties(object obj)
{
    var toret = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();

    foreach(PropertyInfo pinfo in properties) {
        toret.Add( pinfo.Name, pinfo.GetValue( obj ) );
    }

    return toret;
}
```

For example, for an object like this one:

```
class Foo {
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

You can show the properties names and values of a given object by:

```
class Ppal {
    public static void Main()    
    {
            var foo = new Foo{ A = 5, B = 6 };

            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in GetAllProperties( foo ) ) {
                Console.WriteLine( "Foo.{0} = {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value );
            }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.